# OpenCV BirdEyeView: How do i set the points for the perspective transformation correctly?

Tags: java, opencv, math, perspectivecamera

I try to create a BirdEyeView from a street. First I set the points of the desired section (ImagePoints) and then I set the rectangle (objectivePoints) on which I want to project it.
In the example below it works, but if i change the imagePoints my result get weird.
Could you explain to me what the problem is and give an example of a solution?

Thank you!

I also have data from a camera matrix if that could help:
[1204.8790283203125,0.0,956.2759399414062,0.0,1204.8790283203125,347.5567626953125,0.0,0.0,1.0]

"rotation": {
"x": 0.0016885,
"y": 0.0414801,
"z": 0.0028893,
"w": 0.9991337
}

"translation": {
"x": 2.0180001258850098,
"y": 9.499490261077881E-8,
"z": 1.3799999952316284
}

```
    imagePoints.add(new Point(10,457)); //LL
    imagePoints.add(new Point(395,291)); // UL
    imagePoints.add(new Point(624,291)); // UR
    imagePoints.add(new Point(1000,457)); //LR

    objectivePoints.add(new Point(this.roadView.width()*0.125,this.roadView.height()*0.875)); //LL
    objectivePoints.add(new Point(this.roadView.width()*0.125,this.roadView.height()*0.1));//UL
    objectivePoints.add(new Point(this.roadView.width()*0.875,this.roadView.height()*0.1)); //UR
    objectivePoints.add(new Point(this.roadView.width()*0.875,this.roadView.height()*0.875)); //LR


    public void createBirdEyeView(){
        drawInterestingPoints();
        Mat perspectiveTransform = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(imagePoints),
                Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(objectivePoints));
        Mat BirdEyeView = new Mat();
        Imgproc.warpPerspective(roadView, BirdEyeView, perspectiveTransform,BirdEyeView.size());
        Bird = BirdEyeView;

        Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:\\Users\\steve\\IdeaProjects\\BirdViewWithOpenCV\\resources\\output\\BirdEyeView.png", Bird);
    }
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

Comment: the objective points and the rest of the code do not need to be changed so your new image points are incorrect. the points need to be aligned according to the perspective of the road, if not, you'll get weird results

Comment: Well, all you need to perspective transform to work is consistent ordering on both the original coordinates and the destination/transformed coordinates. So you can choose something like clockwise from top-left to bottom left, for example.